# return(pass) HIT or MISS

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl, varnish-4

I have understand when someone uses return(pass) is because want not cache the content and pass the request to the backend.
So, if this is really so, why a I get HIT in place of MISS.
Here es my vcl:

```
sub vcl_recv{
 if (req.method == "GET" && req.method == "HEAD"){
            return (pass);
    }
```

}

Here a part of varnishlog:

- VCL_call       RECV
- VCL_return     hash
- VCL_call       HASH
- VCL_return     lookup
- Hit            20
- VCL_call       HIT
- VCL_return     deliver

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I found the mistake. I was putting:

```
if (req.method == "GET" && req.method == "HEAD") {
            return (pass);
    }
```

In place of:

```
if (req.method == "GET" || req.method == "HEAD") {
            return (pass);
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Another victory for the rubber duck! (It helps a lot writing and explaining issues to other people (or to a rubber duck) m